# Salesforce Lightning vs Classic Experience

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, einstein-analytics, salesforce-classic, classic

Is there any plans to replace the Salesforce Classic with Salesforce Lightning? Any news or links on this. I just went to through the release note and can see some difference between these - [Compare Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=lex_aloha_comparison.htm&language=en_US)

As per comparison chart its marked as no options for some small things like no  'Pie Chart' , no 'Create report folders' in Lightning etc. Also I can see some limitation marked for Lightning version [Lightning Limitaion](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/lex_gaps_limitations_org_setup.htm). Is there any other Limitation other than this? So is it means like currently the Lightning version is still under modifications for future changes?

Comment: Lightning is still being improved with each release.  The summer 16 release allows for the export of reports in lightning, but you still need to save reports to run them (a mess for Admins). Are you looking for report specific difference or all Lighting difference to Classic?

Comment: @MeighanRocksSF thxn for reply.. I am referring  to all  Lighting difference to Classic in General

Comment: Oh wow, that's s quite the list. I will take a look at the Salesforce differences between Lighting and Classic today and add what I know off hand to it for you on lunch today. I know it won't cover everything, but I will share what I know to help. :-)

Comment: *ONE* of the most basic things that stops people from complete switch to LEX is the inability to add custom buttons to the Page Layout like you can in classic. Currently ALL button have to be rewritten using a Lightning Compatible solution. IMHO I think it will never be mainstream or do away with classic due to the choice is architecture. Time will probably prove me wrong though

Comment: @Eric That's true. It's not just that, several other features are still not supported in Lightning (backend as well as front end). Hopefully Salesforce will clear all the roadblocks as soon as possible as apps built using Lightning Components and the LDS are awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some research on this and I found out the answer for My question. I am sharing all the findings below in case someone need to refer this in future.

1) I got some interesting detailed explanation on this from Link. [Click_here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/understanding-salesforce-classic-lightning-experience-amit-goyal)
, I am copying some important facts from this as below

**Salesforce Classic:** It's the platform which we are using from long time as standard, Salesforce just named to classify between the new User Interface/Experience and old User Interface/Experience.

**Lightning Experience**: It's the new, slick user interface and the Lightning Component framework is a UI framework for developing dynamic web apps for mobile and desktop devices. Lightning makes it easier to build responsive applications for ANY DEVICE. The initial release of the new user interface is geared towards sales reps with an intuitive interface that allows sales reps to work more efficiently. `The dashboard and charts in Lightning Experience behave much like Wave where changes in the chart recalculates in real time.` While the new interface is easy to enable, *It may not be suited for everyone as there are some missing functionalities at this point of time. In the future releases salesforce would eliminate those gaps, but keep safe harbor statement in mind.*

2) Also you can get a good knowledge about the `Qualification of ORG` to be with Lightning Experience from **Trail heads**
- [Does My Org Qualify for Lightning Experience?](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/lex_migration_introduction/lex_migration_introduction_rightforme)

3) Also an Interesting read about this comparison also here - [Salesforce Classic or Lightning? Hamburger vs. Sushi](http://www.absi.be/salesforce-lightning-or-classic/) -- Its a really Good article to read

4) [Comparison chart on - Lightning Experience VS Salesforce Classic](http://advancedcommunities.com/lightning-experience-vs-salesforce-classic/)

Comment: Also please find a Good read on this - http://www.businessinsider.com.au/salesforce-finally-gives-itself-a-much-needed-new-look-after-16-years-heres-why-2015-8?r=US&IR=T

Comment: I don't think it's just for the desktop browser UI. The Lightning Component framework is a UI framework for developing dynamic web apps for mobile
and desktop devices. 

Lightning makes it easier to build
responsive applications for ANY DEVICE (I believe this is the main point rather than saying desktop browser UI).

Comment: @AravindAjith thnx for correction. Its updated above as well.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding the current Limitations on New Lightning Platform, please refer below links

- [What's not supported yet?](http:////www.soapboxengage.com/blog/252-what-is-it-the-lightning-experience-and-should-i-enable-it-for-my-organization)
- [Release Note - What’s Not Available in Lightning Experience](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/lex_gaps_limitations.htm)

Salesforce is working on the next releases to fill these gap/limitation above  mentioned to make it accessible to wider platform without any restriction. Just wait for the future releases from salesforce to get more out of Lightning Platform.